# Oracle/ Sql Developer Saving Sys_Refcursor Output Variable to excel

Tags: excel, oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to run an Oracle stored procedure that returns a SYS_REFCURSOR and save the results to an excel file. I'm using Sql Developer Version 4.0.1.14 on Oracle 17c.

I don't need to do this in the stored procedure, I get asked to send other developers the output from the procedure.

When I right click on the package holding procedure, I can run it fine. I tried copy and paste the result set but I can't copy the column names.

When I run the procedure as a script (F5):

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec APP_PACKAGE.GETDATA(11, :rc );
print rc;
```

I get a format that doesn't work for Excel. The sys_refcursor I basically need the same output as 'Query Result', with a grid format.

Seems like this ought to be simple, but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: I think you can loop over the `Fields` property to get the column names. Maybe check this one: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17726/using.htm#OLEDB168

Comment: I would write a function that returns the refcursor, and then just run your SELECT statement and use the built-in Excel support